# How can I transform an Excel file using DataWeave?

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have the following XML, which is inside an Excel (.xlsx) file. I want to put the word "test" in all the Country columns:

```
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><dimension ref="A1"/><sheetViews><sheetView workbookViewId="0" tabSelected="true"/></sheetViews><sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="15.0"/><sheetData>
<row r="1">
<c r="A1" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>FirstName</t></is></c><c r="B1" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>MiddleName</t></is></c><c r="C1" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>LastName</t></is></c><c r="D1"
t="inlineStr"><is><t>Street</t></is></c><c r="F1" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>State</t></is></c><c r="G1" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>PostalCode</t></is></c><c r="H1" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>Country</t></is></c><c r="I1" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>Birthdate</t></is></c><c r="J1"</row> 
<row r="2">
<c r="A2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>Willy</t></is></c><c r="B2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t></t></is></c><c r="C2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>Kelly</t></is></c><c r="D2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>1234 TEST</t></is></c><c r="F2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>TE</t></is></c><c r="G2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>12345</t></is></c><c r="H2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t></t></is></c><c r="I2" 
t="inlineStr"><is><t>1997-15-08T00:00:00</t></is></c><c r="J2"
</row>
<row r="3">
```

Mule Runtime version 4.4.0 EE

Comment: Few suggestions when you ask question. 
    1. Give a valid xml/json inputs. The example you gave is not valid, so please update it. We do not need the full payload, just a minimal example to understand the data
    2. Preferably format the XMLs and JSONs so that readers can understand what kind of data you are dealing with just by looking.

Comment: The zip format on how you extract the file name seem to be irrelevant for the question. Also the input shown is an XML, not a CSV, and as @HarshankBansal mentioned it is truncated/incomplete and can not be used. Please provide a sample that it is valid.

Comment: I already edited the question

Comment: @WillyKelly Still not a valid XML

Comment: That is the payload that is returned when I extract a zip, how could I manipulate it?

Comment: I said it's XML because the header says so

Answer (score 0):

DataWeave already supports reading and writing Excel (.xlsx) files natively, with [some restrictions](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-formats-excel#limitations). You don't need to decompress the .xlsx file, nor find the right XML. Just ensure the MIME type of the input file is `application/xlsx`. You can force it in most connectors if needed with the attribute `outputMimeType="application/xlsx"`.

Then the DataWeave script to transform is something simple like:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.mytabname 
  map ($ update {
        case .Country ->  "test"
  })
```

Replace `mytabname` by the tab or sheet name that contains the table.